# Click Events Not Triggering in OpenLayers 6.5 with Java Webview

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I recently upgraded our Openlayers version from 3 to 6.5 and began having an issue with various interactions and listeners and unable to figure out why. All of this worked with no issues in OL 3

Environment: OpenLayers 6.5 rendered through a Java WebView

Problem: Neither map.on("click"), SelectInteractions, DragPanInteractions nor DrawInteractions are triggering for no discernible reason.

Debugging so far: I have confirmed that the map is fully rendering (all layers render, I can add features through other means, etc). I have added a click listener to the html body and confirmed that click isn't being eaten. I have confirmed that addInteraction, on, map, and the interactions themselves are all defined when they're referenced.

Code:

Map Definition

````
  var map = new ol.Map({
      target : 'map',
      layers : layers,
      pixelRatio : 1,
      view : new ol.View({
          projection : latLonProj,
          center : [ 0, 0 ],
          extent : [ Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, -90, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 90 ],
          zoom : 3.5,
          zoomFactor : 1.5,
          minZoom : 3.5
      }),
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
          dragPan: false,
          mouseWheelZoom: false
      }).extend([
          new ol.interaction.DragPan({kinetic: false}),
          new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom({duration: 0})
      ])
  });
  ```
SelectInteraction
  ```
  var selectedCountries = [];
  var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
              condition : ol.events.condition.click,
              toggleCondition : function(evt) {
                  ...business logic
              },
              style : new ol.style.Style({
                  fill : new ol.style.Fill({
                      color : 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                  }),
                  stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
                      color : '#f00',
                      width : 1
                  }),
              })
          });
     ```
     
     Adding/Removing the Interaction (Called through jsConnector from Java controller)
     ```
      setSelectMode : function(enable) {
          console.log("SetSelectMode: " + enable);
          selectMode = enable;
          map.removeInteraction(selectInteraction);
          
          _selectMode = selectMode;
          
          if (!selectMode) {
              return;
          }
          
          map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);  

      }
      ```
````

Comment: Have you included pointer event polyfills? See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.4.0

Comment: @Mike I had not. I just tried that (and removing ol.css just in case since that document mentions interactions not working with it) without success. I'm playing with it more to make sure I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Edit: Realized I misread the part about ol.css. It appears in previous versions not having the css broke interactions, but I do have it and am past this version.